# Reloading page after leaving it

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have built a website using codeigniter php, I have an `anchor` on a page with `target="_blank"` and a link to another page, I want that when ever user click on that `anchor` it should open new tab with path in `href` but alongside reload the same page. how to do this?

I need this because on click of that anchor I have to set a status which should show whenever user reopen same tab.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: jquer on method maybe? :  `$("a.nchor").on("click", function(){location.reload();});`

Comment: not working i am sending to controler function which sets status and then redirect to specific url.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will work for you if you are just redirecting to another link and performing no task on server.

```
$(".yourClass").on("click", function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

If you are performing some task on server and it taking some time even a nano second then I think so you need a little improvement in above code by adding timeout to your server task performing time as I added to 5 sec.

```
$(".yourClass").on("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one is working for me, as i am setting some status in controler function, Thanks again, i was stucked.